# How to choose the right .symbols file to deobfuscate a stacktrace from crashlytics

Tags: flutter, obfuscation, crashlytics, firebase-crash-reporting

After I release obfuscated flutter app to playstore, all the stacktrace in crashlytics dashboard are are not readable. I found this command to deobfuscate the stacktrace:

```
flutter symbolize -i stacktrace_obfuscated.txt -d  "$HOME"/debuginfo/app.android-arm64.symbols
```

The problem is, there is 3 .symbols files are generated after the build, `app.android-arm64.symbols`, `app.android-arm.symbols`, `app.android-x64.symbols`, and I tried to deobfuscate the stacktrace with all of them, and I got 3 readable different stacktrace.

The question is: how can I choose the right .symbols to deobfuscate the stacktrace?

Answer (score 0):

Recently a new feature was included to support Flutter apps built with `--split-debug-info` and `--obfuscate` flags on Android. This could help you avoid doing this step to deobfuscate the crash reports.

See [this](https://firebase.google.com/support/releases#crashlytics-flutter-symbolication-support) for reference.